# Resetting an R Shiny App while not restarting it

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a Shiny app. It works fine, but when I am refreshing the browser it is in, the app seemingly returns to its initial stage. How can I prevent it so that whenever I refresh I also remain in my present page?

To replicate the problem I am attaching the following example of a shiny app. How can I refresh it while preserving the last value I set it on?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

# App title ----
titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

# Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
sidebarLayout(

# Sidebar panel for inputs ----
sidebarPanel(

# Input: Slider for the number of bins ----
sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
label = "Number of bins:",
min = 1,
max = 50,
value = 30)

),

# Main panel for displaying outputs ----
mainPanel(

# Output: Histogram ----
plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")

)
)
)


 

server <- function(input, output) {

# Histogram of the Old Faithful Geyser Data ----
# with requested number of bins
# This expression that generates a histogram is wrapped in a call
# to renderPlot to indicate that:
#
# 1. It is "reactive" and therefore should be automatically
# re-executed when inputs (input$bins) change
# 2. Its output type is a plot
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

x <- faithful$waiting
bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
main = "Histogram of waiting times")

})

}


 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Have a look at bookmarking https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html